# Video and LAN Cards are not recognized on Intel DG41RQ MB

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet

My 32 bit Debian Etch with Etch-n-Half kernel 2.6.24 and Etch-n-half video driver xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.2.1-1~etchnhalf2 does not recognize my on-board LAN and Video.

I can work only with VESA display. And additional PCI LAN card (that I wanted to use for Cross-X-Cabel).

output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR/GH (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 01)
04:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10
```

According to MB Spec:

```
Video: Intel G41 Express Chipset Graphics and Memory Controller Hub Graphics (GMCH)
LAN: Realtek 8111D Gigabit Ethernet Controller LAN Support
```

When I run `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` is suggest i810 driver but X does not start, it
does not start with intel driver as well; only vesa.

LAN I even can't find in lspci... the last Realtek card is external one 100MB card.

Where to start from?

Comment: please post your latest x-org logs for us to troubleshoot effectively.

Comment: OK, I'll add as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your NIC in BIOS.  Boot your computer and you might be surprised to find the video working correctly.  Then reboot and enable the NIC in BIOS.  Upon booting, both are working fine.  There is some hardware or interrupt conflict that the OS cant resolve when both are being detected at the same time...

This fix has worked for me in both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There has been reported problems of the G41 chipset when used with older distros and kernels -   reportedly the issue has been cleared with 2.6.28 kernels and above.

I recommend you :

1. update to the latest stable kernel
2. also, there are some reports that the new HDCP content protection settings in BIOS might interfere - PAVP or something. Hunt and disable if found.
3. do an update for latest packages (apt-get -u upgrade)

For LAN - don't bother, just go out there and buy a supported LAN card and plug it in.

Let us know what's the outcome(s).

Comment: About LAN -- I have only 2 PCI slots... One I already use for additional LAN I don't want to use both of them for LAN.

Comment: Oh, you got two 10/100 points from your PC? 1 is on the mobo, and 1 is on the PCI?

Comment: Yes. I need two -- one for modem and another for Cross-X-Cabel. Only the PCI LAN is recognized

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see if anyone actually answered or found anything usefull, so here's a suggestion you can drop if a solution's no longer needed.

I often find that some of the Live distro's find nice creative ways to solve hardware issues with hard to sove hardware issues.
So what I usually do is get some of the latest Live distro's available boot them and leech the logs from these as they start X or whatever I need to snif.

Could be worth trying if you didn't get the problem solved.